# DataTemplateSelector dont add items in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I`m trying to use datatemplates with a DataTemplateSelector. I want to choose 1 of 2 templates that i have, while the program is running.

So I have 2 Simple Templates:

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="User_Text_Message">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UsCom}" Foreground="Black"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Anastasia_Text_Message">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Answer}" Foreground="Yellow"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

     <t:MessagesAdd 
                User_Text_Message="{StaticResource User_Text_Message}"  
                Anastasia_Text_Message="{StaticResource Anastasia_Text_Message}"
                x:Key="MessAdd"/>
```

A ListView

```
 <ListView x:Name="MainChat"  Height="330" Background="{x:Null}" 
                      Margin="10,25,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Width="680" Foreground="White" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MessAdd}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesAdd}">
            </ListView>
```

And Code

```
    class MessagesAdd : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate Anastasia_Text_Message { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate User_Text_Message { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {

            switch(MainLogic.MainVars.TemplateType)
            {
                case 1:
                    var g = new UserTextCommand() { UsCom = MainLogic.MainVars.UserCommand };
                    MainWindow.Instance.MainChat.Items.Add(g);
                    return User_Text_Message;
                case 2:
                    var a = new AnastasiaTextAnswer() { Answer = MainLogic.MainVars.AnastasiaAnswer };
                    MainWindow.Instance.MainChat.Items.Add(a);
                    return Anastasia_Text_Message;       
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

class UserTextCommand
{
    public string UsCom { get; set; }
}

class AnastasiaTextAnswer
    {  
        public string Answer { get; set; }

    }
```

Then I type "Hello" and Click SendButton

```
     public void AnswersADD()
     {
            MainLogic.MainVars.TemplateType = 1;
            add.SelectTemplate(null, null);

            MainLogic.MainVars.TemplateType = 2;
            add.SelectTemplate(null, null);
     }
```

And what I have. There is no my message and only many answers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxdvL.jpg

Cant understand what I must do.

Now I do that

```
 public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            ObservableCollection<AnswersLogic.AnastasiaTextAnswer> answer = new ObservableCollection<AnswersLogic.AnastasiaTextAnswer>();
            ObservableCollection<AnswersLogic.UserTextCommand> usercom = new ObservableCollection<AnswersLogic.UserTextCommand>();

            if (item is UserTextCommand)
            {
                usercom.Add(new UserTextCommand() { UsCom = MainLogic.MainVars.UserCommand});

                MainWindow.Instance.MainChat.ItemsSource = usercom;
                return User_Text_Message;
            }
            else if (item is AnastasiaTextAnswer)
            {
                answer.Add(new AnastasiaTextAnswer() { Answer = MainLogic.MainVars.AnastasiaAnswer });
                MainWindow.Instance.MainChat.ItemsSource = answer;
                return Anastasia_Text_Message;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

but there is infinity circle in

```
 MainWindow.Instance.MainChat.ItemsSource = usercom;
```

and

```
MainWindow.Instance.MainChat.ItemsSource = answer;
```

Comment: Do you have any errors or messages? Also, what happens if you put a break point just before your switch statement? If you step through does it do as you expect?

Comment: A DataTemplateSelector is not meant to add items to the ItemsSource where it's used. Do not call `MainWindow.Instance.MainChat.Items.Add(...)`.

Comment: If i dont call MainWindow.Instance.MainChat.Items.Add(...) nothing happens

Comment: I put break point on  return Anastasia_Text_Message; . There is a circle , but i cant explain why

Comment: There is a fundamental lack of your understanding about how an ItemsControl and DataTemplates work. When you write `ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesAdd}"`, there must be a public collection property named `MessagesAdd` in the DataContext object of the ListView (also called the view model). This is usually an ObservableCollection, so that adding or removing elements would notify the ListView. Read the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN to get a basic understanding.

Comment: Also essential: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx). Without reading and understanding these articles all you do is poking in the dark.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is MainLogic.MainVars.TemplateType? I don't see how that is going to be different based on which item is passed to the SelectTemplate method. Also, I'm not sure why you are adding things in this selector. It should provide a template, and that is all. Like this:

```
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {

        if (item is UserTextCommand)
        {
            return User_Text_Message;
        }
        else if (item is AnastasiaTextAnswer)
        { 
            return Anastasia_Text_Message;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

You are getting items of all the same template because MainLogic.MainVars.TemplateType does not change. You are getting more items than you expect because you are adding more in the selector.

Comment: MainLogic.MainVars.TemplateType  is simple Int var

Comment: Yes. Now it add my message but there is 2 circle. If i dont call MainChat.Items.Add() nothing happens  . I cant understand how to add items

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesAdd}" sets the content. You add items to the MessagesAdd that you have your listview bound to. I'd suggest trying to make it work without a template sector and just one template, then add the selector when its working.